# How to identify yourself on a CV

Tags: culture, job-role

So here is your job role:

- You help in designing common modules that allow other teams to easily deploy their code onto production. This includes Java code, dockerfiles, ansible modules, build pipeline configurations, etc.
- You help promote DevOps practices for both other developer teams and the operation teams
- You are partially responsible for the staging environments
- You are responsible for investigating technologies that help the applications scale better and be more reliable

How would you identify your team? How would you identify yourself? You know that you could cheat and include DevOps in your name, but [that would be wrong](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/468/how-do-i-hire-a-good-devops-fitting-my-company). On the other hand you want to be more specific, so a simple Software Engineer won't cut it, especially since you want the <strike>annoying</strike> recruiters to contact you for jobs related to this practice, not just because you like it, but because you know [the average salary is also higher](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2016#work-salary).

Answer (score 3):

Technically mentioning DevOps *might* be wrong (the question you referenced is also subject to opinions).

But it can also be seen as clarifying/disambiguating - the term is widely used presently on the job market, not only according to your salary reference but also from the job ads themselves - see [What is the difference between Sysadmin and DevOps Engineer?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/157/what-is-the-difference-between-sysadmin-and-devops-engineer).

You'd only speak the recruiters' language - which is IMHO more important from the communication perspective than potentially being technically correct.

Language and culture are fluid - something wrong may become de-facto correct and vice-versa.