# What is the difference between DevOps engineer Vs DevOps consultant Vs DevOps architect?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between DevOps engineer Vs DevOps consultant Vs DevOps architect?

Considering Role wise & Salary wise & Seniority wise & job demand wise, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An ***architect*** is somebody who thinks and creates designs.

A ***consultant*** is somebody who gets hired for things like "Teach us how to do so and so", or to answer questions like "What's your opinion about this design?".

An ***engineer*** is the one who is objective oriented and pragmatic, something along the lines like "*How can I get that design (created by the architect, and validated by the consultant) implemented and make it work"?*.

Their *salaries* may vary (there are cheap and expensive ones), same for *seniority* (there are juniors and seniors, while everybody starts as junior, not all of them ever make it to senior). And *job demand* is pretty variable (by region, over time, economical factors, depending on hypes, etc).

BTW, it doesn't really matter what the actual "subject" is, it could be "IT", it could be "Road Construction", or it could even be "DevOps" ...

PS: What's in a name (or jobtitle), how about a ***DevOps BA***, as shown in [this post](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/activity:6309024601095704576/) ...

Comment: Nitpicking about the engineer and object oriented link here (one does not necessarily implies the other) on what is overall an excellent answer !

Comment: @Newtopian merci for the comment, though I'm not sure what "Nitpicking" means (and I don't have a dictionary handy ...). About Object Oriented: that's like in *OOP*, aka Object Oriented Programming, whereas the "Object" is to get the "Programming" done ... (the definition I was ever given by an old school mainframe programmer ...).

Comment: nitpicking --> "pinailler", "Trébucher sur les fleurs du tapis", "Chercher des poux" etc  as in I was the one doing the nitpicking here pointing this out.  I see now what you meant with Object Oriented and it makes perfect sense.  Might I suggest Objective Oriented as to disambiguate from the programming paradigm OOP towards which my first thoughts went to when I read your post.

Comment: Hey @Newtopian : please go ahead and suggest an edit to my post (I'll probably approve it) ... PS, I found my dictionary ... you mean "***muggezifterij***" (your turn to go find a Dutch dictionary if you want to QA-test my translation ...)

Comment: Tests passed... 100% coverage and approved for production !

Comment: Merci @Newtopian ... also for the suggested edit ... as you may have noticed: I just issued the final (only in this case ...) approval of it.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check the accepted answer to this question:
[Why shouldn't I try to hire a 'DevOps Engineer'?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/797/why-shouldnt-i-try-to-hire-a-devops-engineer)

Or maybe the article "[7 DevOps roles you need to succeed](https://techbeacon.com/7-devops-roles-you-need-succeed)", which includes these (critical?) roles:

1. DevOps evangelist
2. Release manager
3. Automation architect
4. Software developer/tester
5. Experience assurance (XA) professional
6. Security engineer
7. Utility technology player

Comment: Hey Mr. "J" ... the article you linked to doesn't mention a role like "BA for DevOps", any idea why not? And/or what such "BA for DevOps" actually means?

Comment: Links are helpful, but it's encouraged that you [provide context](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and quote relevant sections, plus add your own commentary. See: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for the current guidelines for answering with a link.

Comment: Hey Mr. "J" (again) ... please QA-review the edit I applied to your post, trying to address the comment (and possibly downvote?) from @Aurora0001 ... feel free to rollback if you don't like my edit at all ... PS: where is the DevOps "***Manager***" in that article (= the one who doesn't have to do anything, if everybody else does his/her job, except from approving budgets and things like that)?

Comment: Hi @Pierre.Vriens - thanks for editing. PM might be quite unrelated to DevOps context. DevOps BA is sth I would like to establish. Give me 15 minutes to add two relevant links here. In short, BA (Business Analyst) in scrum terms means product owner, e.g. CI/CD infrastructure is an internal organizational  product.

Comment: ^^ [1] DevOps for PM https://www.agilealliance.org/resources/sessions/a-gentle-introduction-to-devops-project-manager-edition/  [2] https://www.google.de/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/ITCareerQuestions/comments/4fz5vf/in_the_age_of_devopscloudautomation_where_does/