# Where would DevOps Engineers mostly look for their next opportunity and what would it be?

Tags: azure-devops

Where do DevOp Engineers find their next opportunity? Users Groups, Associations, Job Boards?

What do DevOps look for in their next role?

Comment: hi and welcome @michaelg! I have allowed myself to give your question a more precise title. Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that the term **DevOps** refers to both a *Strategies* and *Tactics*.
For instance, the *strategies* of Continuous deployment and Consistent development/production environment.
The *tactics* may be using Kubernetics for deployment to the cluster with Docker for development/production environment.
With that said, a DevOps shop will likely use Kubernetics and Docker as their tactical tools and would look for people with those skillsets.

**ALSO**, they would look for people who are a CULTURAL fit who would work well in a collaborative environment.  If your background is let's say operational and your not open to learning programming skills(or learn what the programmers need), don't take ownership of a project or work well in a team...you will **NOT** be a fit for the company (*you won't get hired*).

As far as the best place to find a DevOps related job?

I would look at going to a DevOps [Meetup](https://meetup.com/), go to trainings/seminars where DevOps tactics and tools are taught (i.e. Docker, Vagrant, Ansible, Kubernetics, etc.), look for certain keywords in the posts such as [SRE (Site Reliability Engineer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_Reliability_Engineering), Systems Automation, etc... and do some research on companies that are moving to or have [embraced DevOps Strategy](https://techbeacon.com/10-companies-killing-it-devops).

If you understand these things, I believe it will give you a great advantage at landing a job in one of those companies.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen that your next DevOps job finds *you* if you have a well elaborated LinkedIn profile and patient enough to deal with and filter/process requests.

Though, my market observations are that many offerings are like:

- DevOps Engineers seen as "full stack developer 2.0", that is as an addon to specific developer skill set you can also setup automation pipelines and deploy to production.
- DevOps Engineers seen as "admin 2.0" to build up automated operational infrastructures
- DevOps Engineers seen as "teams glue" i.e. a company resource pool used to fire up slow/less successfull teams, here at least there is an understanding of how important beyond tech also culture/human communication is, too.
- Sometimes you get also a weird skill set list where nobody really knows where it comes from and what exactly the role is expected to deliver. Buzz wording detected.

Please consider also this post: [Why shouldn't I try to hire a 'DevOps Engineer'](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/797/why-shouldnt-i-try-to-hire-a-devops-engineer)?

Answer (score 0):

Companies either have straight-away openings for DevOps Engineers, either under this specific title or (since the title is a bit misplaced if you really think about what it means in the opinion of some people); or you can look for positions that have some other title but mention DevOps and similar things (for example, "automation", "tooling", "CI/CD" etc.) in the description.

Or in other words - they find jobs the same way everybody else does. It's not *that* magical of a job description...

What they look for, in my experience from plenty of interviews, is simply working with all the tooling/automation we have these days, and most times with a focus on doing as little straightaway programming as possible (i.e., programming in the non-DevOps way; domain-based programming). This separates them mainly from developers who *also* can do the "DevOps" stuff.