# Should I implement Devops on a small project. Is it too big for it?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

Just like the headline suggested, is it too big to implement devOps on a private application I'm solely developing. I mean creating the pipelines, continuous testing and continuous deployment.

And if I must do it for learning purpose which is the main intent. Is it fun to carry out? How's the learning curve and won't I waste too much of my development time? I'm curious enough to go down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Devops is an organization pattern, if you're alone on your project there's not much point in organizing yourself. Having a ci/cd to do the unit and integration tests and then deploy is just automating the lifecycle of your app. You apply devops methodology to a team, not a project.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm trying to incorporate it for learning purpose basically

Comment: DevOps is a culture that aims to make software development better. It's not *just* an enterprise buzzword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2721/can-i-found-a-small-company-on-devops

Answer (score 3):

The question you need to answer is "would I find it entertaining to set up a CI/CD environment if not to learn from it then just for the fun of it?".
You *may* not *need* it at this point in your project or it *may* benefit you. That I can't tell from the limited information. Linux started as a personal project, too. I set up something similar for my own pet project and I've gotta admit I feel a little bit proud every time I compile and deploy with a single click.

Should you implement it? That's for you to decide.